# How to create Sprite (javax.microedition.lcdui.game.Sprite) from SVGImage (SVG Tiny)?

Tags: java-me, svg, sprite, midp

I'm developing a j2me (Java ME) game right now. With a complex requirement of an accessible and mutate-able text inside an image as a sprite, I'm thinking about SVG (tiny) to implement it.

Main goal:

> Creating sprite (javax.microedition.lcdui.game.Sprite) based on SVGImage so it can be included on LayerManager

Question
How to achieve that, is there any alternative? In MIDP 3.0, it can be achieved by using the new api, but my targeted device is MIDP 2.1.

Comment: does your target device support [JSR 226 Mobile SVG](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=226) or  [JSR 287 Mobile SVG 2.0](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=287)?

Comment: I thought so. My Target devices are Nokia Asha series

Comment: do you know how JSR 226 allows to bind SVG image with MIDP `Graphics` object? If not, take a look at online tutorial at SDN: [Getting Started with Mobile 2D Graphics for J2ME](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/s2dvg/index.html). From there, you could likely use it in image, sprite etc.